# findAll Iterable AND Pageable in Spring Data

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

We can do a `List<MyInfo> findAll(List<Integer> ids)` in spring data. How do i combine this with pagination?

On the lines of:

```
findAll(ids, pageRequest);
```

I tried something on the lines of creating a specification and using that, but i'm doing something wrong:

```
public class MySpecs {

    public static Specification<MyInfo> idsIn(final List<Integer> ids)
    {

        return new Specification<MyInfo>() {

            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<MyInfo> root,
                    CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                return root.get("id").in(ids);


            }

        };
    }
}


myRepo.findAll(MySpecs.isIn(ids),pageRequest)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to simply declare a query method like this:

```
interface MyInfoRepository extends Repository<MyInfo, Integer> {

  Page<MyInfo> findByIdIn(List<Integer> ids, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: Yes! :) Btw You mean `Page<MyInfo>` in the return value? :)

Comment: Yes, changed that :).

Comment: Would this work if the ids size is over 1000 or 40000 or so? Depending on the DB this would fail if the ids are over 1000 or so. Postgres gave me the following error "Tried to send an out-of-range integer as a 2-byte value"

Answer (score 0):

This was never a problem. In fact, what I have mentioned above *is correct* and works.

My result set had just 1 row, and i was checking results from page 1 sized 5. Pagination, like everything else, starts from 0.

If anyone reads this, this is not a problem. If you encounter the same problem, please verify the index of the page you are requesting/testing with.

Good night.